# Input leakage current affect on CMOS multiplexer ( TMUX1208 )

Tags: current-measurement, multiplexer, cmos, texas-instruments

I am working on a board that operates with the current range up to pico ampere, I am looking to include a mux to provide multiplexing (8:1 multiplexer) between the sensor and the MCU within this current range. Most of the multiplexer datasheet provides the working voltage range, but regarding the current, there is only leakage current information.

Currently, I was looking into (TMUX1208 5-V Bidirectional 8:1, 1-Channel Multiplexer). Again in the features, the supply current is mentioned.

[image]

Other than that, leakage current information is mentioned.

[image]

Here the input leakage current is mentioned to be of order uA, How does input leakage current affect the output of a CMOS multiplexer. Can anyone please guide me with this or if you have any other suggestion please let me know,

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you find a microcontroller with less than 1pA of input leakage current? Can you provide a link to the datasheet for the multiplexer?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sorry for that, I am using a chipset which performs electrochemical operations in that range (AD5940)

Comment: Try looking at the very old 4000 series CMOS, their muxes seem to be very low leakage. Reed relays could be good. But better to do as Andy says and buffer each channel before the mux, LMC660 for instance has typical room temperature leakage in the fA range.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson link to the [multiplexer](http://www.ti.com/product/TMUX1208)

Comment: @Neil_UK, Thank you very much for the suggestion, even 4000 series CMOS mux have leakage current in nA range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does input leakage current affect the output of a CMOS
>   multiplexer.

If either your source or load are high impedance (resistance) then the leakage current (in or out) multiplied by that high resistance produces an error voltage on top of your signal voltage.

> I am working on a board that operates with the current range up to
>   pico ampere

Tricky and likely to be "a fail" using conventional devices like the one you listed unless your source is AC with a known frequency that can be dragged from the spurious DC level and noise with a filter or lock-in amplifier.

Comment: Andy, Thank you for your answer, The board consists of a chipset which performs electrochemical operations up to pico ampere current range, Is it possible to find a mux to do multiplexing with this range?

Comment: I would say not but, remember this is not a shopping site and if anyone recommends a device it's because they are being especially helpful. I would strongly suggest that you use a transimpedance amplifier (TIA) of some sort to buffer each current source (ion beams?) and convert to a voltage before the multiplexing. And, you'll need a TIA with very good specification op-amp i.e. look for an op-amp with femto amp leakage current at the inputs. There are some at TI and ADI to name a couple.